# How do you use an operation written in another file in Q#?

Tags: import, quantum-computing, q#

File A has

```
Operation Foo() : () {
   body{
      ...
   }
}
```

I want to use Foo in another operation in File B

```
Operation Bar() : (){
   // How to use Foo?
}
```

File A and B may not be in the same folder.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to making this work: namespaces and project references.

All operations (and pretty much everything else) in Q# are in some namespace. Check the `namespace` directives at the tops of the two files; if the namespace names are the same, you're done with this part. If not, then in file B add an `open` directive at the top of the `namespace` that references the namespace for file A:

```
namespace A {
    open B;
```

If files A and B are in the same folder (same project, if using full Visual Studio), then that's all you need. If not, then you need to add a reference from project B to project A. In Visual Studio, you right-click on project B, choose Add, and then Reference..., click Project on the left of the dialog that comes up, and select project A. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager for more details.

If you're using Visual Studio Code, then use the `dotnet add reference` command to add a reference to project A from project B. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference.